# Trouble finding multivariable limit of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

We are required to find the limit of $f(x,y)$, as $(x,y)$ approaches $(1,1)$, where

$f(x,y)=1$,      if $x+y \geq2$

$f(x,y)=-1$,      if $x+y <2$

**Approach** If we approach the point $(1,1)$ through 2 different paths, viz: $x+y \geq2$ and $x+y <2$, we get the limits as $1$ and $-1$, i.e different. Therefore, the limit does not exist

This is indeed the correct *answer*, (i.e the limit does not exist) however, is this the correct *solution*?  Am I missing something in my idea of "approach"?

If its *not* the correct approach, then I cant think of any other method to solve the question: so any alternate method will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why is it that you call $x+y\geqslant2$ a *path*. A path would be the set $\{(t,1)\mid t\geqslant1\}$. That is, $\lim_{t\to1^+}f(t,1)=1$. Furthermore, $\lim_{t\to1^-}f(t,1)=-1$. So, the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}f(x,y)$ doesn't exist.